# convert character string into integer for modulo operation

Tags: r, type-conversion

I want to map md5 hashed character strings to weekday numbers (0-6) via modulo operation. Therefore I need to transform the character hashes into integers (numeric). I haven't found a way to output the hashes in byte form instead of ascii strings (via `digest` package). Any hints with base R or different approaches appreciated.

Comment: Check the `charToRaw` function.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this function. I cannot use raw output for modulo operations directly, so I have to transform the output into integer/numeric?

Comment: Yes. But keep in mind that maybe the distribution of the produced numbers won't be uniform as some values will have a higher probability to be drawn than others. Check for instance `as.integer(charToRaw("0123456789abcdef")) %% 7` and you'll see that, for instance, the number 5 is produced just once, while other numbers 3 or 2 times.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly was my concern...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you'll require multiple-precision arithmetic, because a single md5 hash has 128 bits, which is too large to fit into a normal integer value. This can be done using the [gmp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) package.

```
library('digest');
library('gmp');
as.integer(do.call(c,lapply(strsplit(sapply(letters,digest,'md5'),''), function(x) sum(as.bigz(match(x,c(0:9,letters[1:6]))-1)*as.bigz(16)^((length(x)-1):0)) ))%%7);
## [1] 3 2 1 1 5 5 5 5 1 4 4 6 5 3 5 4 0 2 0 4 5 4 6 3 6 1
```

Let's break that down:

---

```
sapply(letters,digest,'md5')
##                                  a                                  b                                  c ...
## "127a2ec00989b9f7faf671ed470be7f8" "ddf100612805359cd81fdc5ce3b9fbba" "6e7a8c1c098e8817e3df3fd1b21149d1" ...
```

I wanted to design this algorithm to be vectorized, and decided to use the built-in `letters` vector as 26 arbitrary input values for demonstration purposes. Unfortunately the dream of a fully vectorized algorithm (i.e. with no hidden loops) was dashed right away, since `digest()` is not vectorized for some reason, which is why I had to use `sapply()` here to produce a vector of md5 hashes corresponding to the inputs.

---

```
strsplit(...,'')
## $a
##  [1] "1" "2" "7" "a" "2" "e" "c" "0" "0" "9" "8" "9" "b" "9" "f" "7" "f" "a" "f" "6" "7" "1" "e" "d" "4" "7" "0" "b" "e" "7" "f" "8"
##
## $b
##  [1] "d" "d" "f" "1" "0" "0" "6" "1" "2" "8" "0" "5" "3" "5" "9" "c" "d" "8" "1" "f" "d" "c" "5" "c" "e" "3" "b" "9" "f" "b" "b" "a"
##
## $c
##  [1] "6" "e" "7" "a" "8" "c" "1" "c" "0" "9" "8" "e" "8" "8" "1" "7" "e" "3" "d" "f" "3" "f" "d" "1" "b" "2" "1" "1" "4" "9" "d" "1"
## ...
```

Splits the hashes into character vectors, each element being one hex digit of the hash. We now have a list of 26 character vectors.

---

```
lapply(..., function(x) ... )
```

Process each character vector one at a time. Diving into the function (example output will be given for the value of `x` corresponding to input string `'a'`):

```
match(x,c(0:9,letters[1:6]))-1
##  [1]  1  2  7 10  2 14 12  0  0  9  8  9 11  9 15  7 15 10 15  6  7  1 14 13  4  7  0 11 14  7 15  8
```

This returns the value of each digit as a plain old integer, by finding the index within the hex digit sequence (`c(0:9,letters[1:6])`) and subtracting one.

---

```
as.bigz(...)
## Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 32:
##  [1] 1  2  7  10 2  14 12 0  0  9  8  9  11 9  15 7  15 10 15 6  7  1  14 13 4  7  0  11 14 7  15 8
```

Cast to big integer, required for the arithmetic we're about to do.

---

```
...*as.bigz(16)^((length(x)-1):0)
## Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 32:
##  [1] 21267647932558653966460912964485513216 2658455991569831745807614120560689152  581537248155900694395415588872650752   51922968585348276285304963292200960    649037107316853453566312041152512
##  [6] 283953734451123385935261518004224      15211807202738752817960438464512       0                                      0                                      2785365088392105618523029504
## [11] 154742504910672534362390528            10880332376531662572355584             831136500985057557610496               42501298345826806923264                4427218577690292387840
## [16] 129127208515966861312                  17293822569102704640                   720575940379279360                     67553994410557440                      1688849860263936
## [21] 123145302310912                        1099511627776                          962072674304                           55834574848                            1073741824
## [26] 117440512                              0                                      720896                                 57344                                  1792
## [31] 240                                    8
```

Treating the hash as a big-endian hex number, multiply each digit value by its place value.

---

```
sum(...)
## Big Integer ('bigz') :
## [1] 24560512346470571536449760694956189688
```

Add up each place-value-weighted digit value to get the bigz representation of the hash.

This completes the `lapply()` function. Thus, coming out of the `lapply()` call is a list of bigz values corresponding to the hashes:

```
lapply(..., function(x) ... )
## $a
## Big Integer ('bigz') :
## [1] 24560512346470571536449760694956189688
##
## $b
## Big Integer ('bigz') :
## [1] 295010738308890763454498908323798711226
##
## $c
## Big Integer ('bigz') :
## [1] 146851381511772731860674382282097773009
## ...
```

---

```
do.call(c,...)
## Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 26:
##  [1] 24560512346470571536449760694956189688  295010738308890763454498908323798711226 146851381511772731860674382282097773009 277896596675540352347406615789605003835 196274166648971101707441276945175337351
##  [6] 152164057440943545205375583549802787690 177176961461451259509149953911555923867 104722841650969351697149582356678916643 338417919426764038104581950237023359466 337938589168387959049175020406476846763
## [11] 182882473465429367490220828342074920857 80661780033646501757972845962914093977  251563583963884775614900275564391350478 279860001817578054753205218523665183571 158142488666995307556311659134646734337
## [16] 116423801372716526262639744414150237351 97172586736798383425273805088952414146  316382305028166656556246910315962582893 245775506345085992020540282526076959865 96713787940004003047734284080139522561
## [21] 227309401343419671779216095382349119699 250431221767618781785406207793096585421 33680856367414392588062933086110875192  119974848773126933055729663395967301868 296965764652868210844163281547943654188
## [26] 118199003122415992890118393158735259681
```

This "unlists" the list. Note: I tried `sapply()` instead of `lapply()`, and alternatively `unlist()`, and neither worked. This is probably related to the bigz class, possibly to the fact that a vector of bigz values is actually weirdly encoded as a single vector of raw.

---

```
...%%7
## Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 26:
##  [1] 3 2 1 1 5 5 5 5 1 4 4 6 5 3 5 4 0 2 0 4 5 4 6 3 6 1
```

And finally we can take the modulus on 7.

---

```
as.integer(...)
##  [1] 3 2 1 1 5 5 5 5 1 4 4 6 5 3 5 4 0 2 0 4 5 4 6 3 6 1
```

Last step is to convert back to plain old integer from bigz.